# PCB Layout with AGND and DGND

Tags: pcb-design, grounding

I have to start a layout for a PCB soon, and it contains both AGND and DGND. All the components will be on the top layer of the board (micro-controller, voltage reg, SD card, Inst. Amp etc.) so I am wondering is it better to split the top layer to have analog stuff on one side, and digital on the other, with a small 'bridge' over the split, and have a full solid ground plane underneath, or should I also split the ground plane?

At one point I was thinking it might be an idea to have a separate AGND plane and a separate DGND plane, but this doesn't seem like a good idea.

This is my first time dealing with this type of layout, so any advice is very welcome!

Comment: You should explain what your board does. This question or a closely related one comes up approximately once per week. Did you search the archives? I am one of the people that says never split the ground plane. I don't do it. And if you are a beginner, you are 10x more likely to make your design worse than better by doing it. There are tons of good articles on how to manage grounding. The basic idea is don't route sensitive signals near areas where the GND plane has high current. This means not near fast edged digital signals, and not near fast power switching signals.

Comment: There's a lot of questions in the "Related" side bar dealing with exactly this question. What's so different with your case?

Comment: I did see the related questions, which generally seem to be about specific boards. I was hoping for some general advice. I will have a better look through the questions and see if I can pick up some suggestions. @mkeith thanks for the tip!

Comment: A number of us have answered this type of question, and many of the answers are general enough (i.e. look at rationales in the answers) to apply here. I am also one of those who rarely splits grounds (there are *some* times it is appropriate) as it yields better performance.